# Drupal 7 Module Updates fail using the User Interface with a 500 server error

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal 7.15 site we are testing out, and when I provisioned everything I was able to use the module updater/installer through the web admin interface with no issues.  Now I seem to get a 500 ISE every time I try to install or update a module (either through link or direct upload).

I do not see anything helpful in the system log or in apache's error log.

I can see when I provide a URL or file, the Drupal server does grab it, puts it in /tmp/update-cache/ as it should (I have Drupal config'ed to use /tmp in File System->Temporary Directory), and it extracts the tar.gz to /tmp/update-extraction/

The files never get moved over to sites/all/modules.  Permissions are

> drwxrwxr-x 27 apache webeditors 4096 Sep 12 09:43 modules

apache is a member of webeditors.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Propably you need to increase thr PHP Memory
The quick way:

add `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` to your settings.php

Universal way:
 edit this limit in your php.ini. by finding

> php_value memory_limit 32M and changing to appropriate limit

To find php.ini location run a `phpinfo();`